# Questions about Stommel's Two-Box Model (North Atlantic Current)

Tags: oceanography

I have a question about [a module on Stommel's Two-Box model](https://serc.carleton.edu/integrate/teaching_materials/earth_modeling/student_materials/unit8_article1.html).

I am uncertain about the following density equation:
$ \Delta  \rho =  | R \Delta S - \Delta T| $

A larger difference between temperatures/salinity levels across the two regions of the North Atlantic should both increase the density difference. Why is this a subtraction? Is this because of the opposite relationship between salinity/temperature at each pole (i.e., high salinity increasing the density at the equatorial region with high temp decreasing density at the equatorial region, and vice versa at the poles)?

Comment: Have you looked at the paragraph "It is important to understand an important negative feedback in this system involving Q and the pole-equator temperature difference ΔT. When the temperature difference, ΔT, is great, then Q will be strong, but this transports more heat to the polar region, thus lessening ΔT, which in turn weakens Q. On the other hand, if Q is weak, then there is little heat transport to the polar region, allowing this region to grow colder, thus increasing ΔT, which can then in turn leads to a stronger Q and thus more heat to the polar region." on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifiing my previous answer thanks to you comment, I realized I not clear at all. Here it's better.

First, I want to state that the notations in your material seem weird to me as the normalizing and adimentionnality of the values are not properly presented. For the eq. 1 and 2, $T_{eq}$ and $S_{eq}$ are said to be dimensionless yet they are added to $\Delta T$ and $\Delta S$ that are not introduced as dimensionless.

In any case, it seems akin to the *density anomaly* (see [THIS LINK](https://scholarship.claremont.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1040&context=codee), page 6). The same pdf file the link leads to bears a thorough explanation of the model (page 9 and following).

Without going trough the nondimensionalization process, by taking the density equation of salty waters, $\rho=\rho_0(1-\alpha T+\beta S)$ (increases with increasing S and decreases with increasing T with rate respectively $\alpha$ and $\beta$), you have that \begin{align}\Delta \rho&=\rho_{A}-\rho_{B}\\&=\rho_0(1-\alpha T_{A}+\beta S_{A})-\rho_0(1-\alpha T_{B}+\beta S_{B})\\&=\rho_0(-\alpha \Delta T+\beta \Delta S).\end{align} Using $R=\frac{\beta}{\alpha}$ and $\Delta \rho_*=\frac{\Delta \rho}{\alpha\rho_0}$ leads to $$\Delta\rho_*=-\Delta T+R\Delta S.$$ I'm not sure about why the absolute value is introduced, maybe because the textbook authors weren't interested in wich part of the ocean was the most dense?

You can take a look at the original paper by Stommel at he following [LINK](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/j.2153-3490.1961.tb00079.x).

Comment: A higher temperature difference across two regions of the ocean also means a higher density difference.

The detlaT and deltaS are between 0 and 1 (always positive):

T_equatorial-T_polar = Positive value;
S_equatorial - S_polar = Positive value.

Comment: Hi @AAAA , I modified my answer to be more thorough . I'm not absolutely sure of being right as it's been a while since I've studied this model. However, your base material is perplexity inducing as it jumps over large parts of the explanation and seems to neglect some precisions - I recommand you to look at other material for a finer understanding.

Comment: Great! Thanks. 
Yes, I have been using my mathematics texts but was hoping to see if there was a more intuitive way of understanding this model.  Thank you for the explanation! I will keep working on it to figure out how else it can be presented.